# What is a key-value memory storage system that is not intended to be persistent, but can store over 1MB?

Tags: database, linux, unix, memcached, storage

Basically, I want memcached that can store over 1MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memcached wiki page on [WhyNotMemcached](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/WhyNotMemcached) suggests [MogileFS](http://danga.com/mogilefs/) as another distributed key/value storage technology that can store objects larger than 1MB.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered memcached?

What are your requirements?  A very large object cache is better suited for things like varnish where latency isn't the most important part of the system  memcached will happily store your 25MB objects, but it won't be noticeably faster than using something else since more time will be spent transferring the object than locating it.